# How to bold title html tag

Tags: html

I see a interesting thing with title tag html, the title tag can bold. Like this page. Anyone know how to do it?
[image: bold title tag]

Comment: it's a particular font used for the title (inspect the element to notice this)

Comment: Do you know what is this font?

Comment: check this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342024

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Edit

Don't do this. As @Quentin said in the first comment, it's bad for A11Y.

Also, not possible to achieve in an accessible way: `<title>` can't be styled using CSS.

---

## Previous answer

One solution is to use the unicode chars of bold text. If you inspect the source of those examples that you quoted, you see this:

[image]

You can copy this line:

CSS Editor -

[Here's a list of unicode chars](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/decomposition/%3Cfont%3E). From `U+1D5D4` on you find the ones you want.

Comment: Don't do this. Those characters are things like "MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL O", they aren't bold versions of regular letters. Abusing them like this causes accessibility problems, especially when they interact with screen reader software.

Comment: Here is a [list of bold unicode characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=Mathematical+Bold#characters), a [list of italic unicode characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=Mathematical+Italic#characters) and a [list of double-struck unicode characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=Mathematical+Double-Struck#characters).

Comment: And [the script style characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=Mathematical+Script#characters).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<strong>` tags inside your normal text tags in HTML (`<p>, <a>, <span>, etc.`)

Styles cannot be applied to the `<title>` tag.

In CSS, you can use the property `font-weight: bold;` on any normal text tags as well.

Comment: @ThanhNgo Can you show an example of your code? What have you tried?

Comment: <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title><strong>The HTML5</strong> Herald</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bold title</h1>
</body>
<style>
h1 {color:red;font-weight: bold;}
title {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
</html>

Comment: I want to know how to bold `<title>` tag

Comment: @ThanhNgo You cannot use any HTML tags within the `<title>` tags. You also cannot apply styles to the `<title>` tags.

Comment: I know can not style for title tag. But this page https://html-css-js.com/css/editor/ can bold title. And I want to know how they can do it. I don't ask how to css for title tag, I ask for how to bold title tag

Comment: They just copied bold text from somewhere and pasted it into the `<title>` tags.

Comment: That's right. I got an answer. They copy from https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/decomposition/%3Cfont%3E
Thanks for your support