# Make title of page bold

Tags: javascript

I tried to make the title of the page bold but the  tag just shows up as a tag instead of making it bold. How do I fix this?

```
document.title = "<b> Text </b>";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bold title html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121872/how-to-bold-title-html-tag)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The title element can only have text node descendants, not elements.

It is primarily used in user interface elements such as favourite menus and browser tabs which are not designed to hold formatted text.